# Non-transitive euclidean relation

Tags: relations, binary-operations

A relation $R$ on a set $X$ is called Euclidean if for all $a, b, c \in X$, if $aRb$ and $aRc$ then $bRc$.

This does not imply transitivity - the relation $\{(a, b), (b, c), (b, b), (c, c), (c, b)\}$ is non-transitive and Euclidean.

I was wondering if there are any "real life examples" of these kinds of relations, which are interesting too?

Answer (score 0):

$x\text{R}y$ defined by $0≤x≤y+1≤2$ is not transitive, but right Euclidean on natural numbers.